# PreferenceScreen themed with honeycomb theme

Tags: android, preferencescreen

i want to make to make an PreferenceActivity with the same style that can be found on the image below.

[Image of Preference Screen Android 3.2 http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/5120/device20120320173903.png](http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/5120/device20120320173903.png)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/600/device20120320173903.png

There any way to make a close match of it or do i need to program the behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways you can do. One is to download the source code, but I think that layout is custom for galaxy tablets.

The other option would be to use the Hierarchy View Perspective in Eclipse to determine the structure and details of the interface and from there replicate the interface.

Good luck!

---

**Udapte:**

Ok, if what you want is the drawables you can actually get them from the tablet. With a file manager in the tablet **copy** the file /System/app/System.apk to the SD card and from there to your computer. There change the extension to .zip and extract the contents. This way you can access only the drawables. The xml files are compiled so you can't see their content.

I think you can use this if you want more data out (like the xml layouts): http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/

Although as I said in the comments I am not sure about the legality of this given this is Samsung's own IP.

Comment: Btw, I forgot to ask, are you trying to replicate the look or the behaviour?

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the look

Comment: Yeah, the look I think is proprietary of Samsung. On the other hand you can still make it 2 columns using Fragments ;)

Comment: That is what i am trying atm. Thanks for the help anyway :)